# Trying to create a grid of JButtons for Minesweeper But Grids Won't Show Until MouseOver

Tags: java

So I have a minesweeper using SWING that won't show the individual boxes until you mouse-over them. This is not what I like it to be. Can someone help? I working on JUST the grid generation. Two class involved: Field (the JFrame) and Tile (the JButton).

Field Class

```
public class Field extends JFrame {

    private final JPanel panel;
    private final Tile[][] field;
    private final int numRows, numCols;
    private final int numMines;

    public Field(int numRows, int numCols, int numMines) {
        super("MineSweeper");
        
        this.numMines = numMines;
        this.numRows = numRows;
        this.numCols = numCols;
        field = new Tile[numRows][numCols];
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(540, 600);
        setResizable(false);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(numRows, numCols));

        for(int y=0; y<numRows; y++) {
            for(int x=0; x<numCols; x++) {
                JButton t = new Tile(x, y);
                panel.add(t);
                field[y][x] = (Tile)t;
            }
        }
        
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
public class Tile extends JButton implements MouseListener{

    private final int xPos, yPos;
    private int numMinesAround;
    private boolean isMine, isFlagged;

    public Tile(int xPos, int yPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;

        numMinesAround = 0;

        isMine = false;
        isFlagged = false;
    }
}
```

This is merely trying to get the JFrame and the JButton boxes to work.

Comment: What happens if you call revalidate or repaint on the panel after its visible?

Comment: @Phaelaxz I don't know anything about swing besides the basic stuff. So, what does repaint/re-validate do?

Comment: revalidate basically tells the layout manager the child components have changed (adding buttons to it). I wouldn't think you'd need to call this but worth a try.  Repaint, simply put, tells it to redraw the component.  So something like panel.repaint() after setVisible

Comment: @Phaelaxz should I call both repaint and revalidate?

Comment: It's not going to hurt anything if you call both. But do the revalidate first then repaint

Comment: 1) Don't set the size of the frame. The size of the frame includes the title bar and border and you don't know what the size of those features are. You should instead override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your `Tile` class to return the preferred size of a Tile. 2) add the components to the frame. 3) invoke pack() on the frame so all the components can be displayed at their preferred size 4) invoke setVisible(...) on the frame. 5) All the above code should be exicuted on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

Comment: If you follow the above steps there is not need to invoke revalidate() and repaint(). Those methods are only needed when you add/remove components to a visible frame.